# How do I get sentence reversal using pointers program to stop printing out jibberish?

Tags: c++, pointers, cstring

My code will compile and run, but the output is jibberish. It's literally just a bunch or random symbols and a few letters.

This is my code:

```
int main()
{
    char words[MAX];
    cout<<"This program will reverse your sentence.\n";


        cout<<"Please enter a sentence (up to 100 characters)\n";
        cin.getline(words,MAX);
        cout<<words<<"\n";
        sentence_reversal(words);
        cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}

void sentence_reversal(char a[])
{
    char *the_front;
    char *rear;
    int i=0;
    rear = &a[i];
    *rear=a[i];
    the_front=&a[i];
    *the_front=a[i];

    for(int i = MAX-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        *rear=a[i];
        cout<<*rear;

    }
delete the_front;
delete rear;

return;
}
```

I have rewritten this code dozens of times and reviewed pointer just as much. I'm trying to understand how to use pointers with char arrays and cstrings. Originally I tried to have the pointers the_front and rear point to char a[] in the function, but I recieved the error:

> cannot convert char to *char.

Now there is no error, but the reversed sentence isn't printing out, just jibberish.

Comment: You appear to be deleting things that were allocated on the stack. Was that intended?

Comment: Are you trying to reverse the string in its storage; or just print out the string in reverse?

Answer (score 1):

You need to start printing from the end of the string, not the end of the buffer.

Comment: I tried that, but it's still printing out random symbols.

Comment: This looks like homework. Is the assignment to print the string in reverse order or to form a new string that contains the initial string, but reversed? If it's just to print, your code is overly complex for that simple task.